# I Don't Understand This Arc Length Formula

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm taking the following from my Stewart's Calculus 7E. This is a introductory section of finding arc length.

[image]

**My Problem**

I follow what they're saying. If we approximate portions of the curve using straight lines, and sum all of these straight lines, we have an approximation of the arc length. Then if we take the limit the number of these approximating straight lines goes to infinity, we get the actual arc length. This is the same idea as integration. However, I'm having trouble understanding their formula. Why does $|P_{i-1}P_{i}|$ represent the length of these approximating straight lines?

Comment: This is just notation. We denote the length of the line segment $AB$ by $|AB|$.

Comment: So they're not saying the absolute value of the $P_{i-1}*P_i$

Comment: How to define a product when $P_1, P_2$ are points in the plane?

Comment: No, that wouldn't make sense! After all, $P_{i-1}$ and $P_i$ are *points*, not numbers.

Comment: Your first step to understanding math is to drop Stewart. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @Ganesh that was what was confusing me

Comment: @UserX I've always found it was good relative to other texts I have used ahaha. What is a better textbook in your opinion?

Comment: @Dunka Spivak.${}{}{}$

Comment: Larson also has a good Calculus book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|P_{i-1}P_i|$ is just *notation* which *means* "the length of the line segment connecting the point $P_{i-1}$ with the point $P_i$".

Answer (score 2):

By the Pythagorean theorem the distance between $ P_{i-1} $ and $ P_i $ is $$|P_{i-1} P_i|=\sqrt {(x_{i-1}-x_i)^2+(y_{i-1}-y_i)^2} . $$

Added. Sometimes, with the same meaning, it's used the notation $ P_{i-1}P_i$ instead of the absolute-value notation.